# Soap film bounded by a circular wire

Tags: fluid-dynamics, variational-principle, surface-tension, variational-calculus

If a soap film is bounded by two parallel circular wires, then the equation of its surface of the minimal area is 
$$
r=c\cosh(z/c)
$$
where $c$ is a constant and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. This can be proven by using the Euler-Lagrange equation.

However, the more common situation we see in our life is a soap film bounded by only ONE circular wire. The shape of the soap film is initially planar but becomes roughly a semisphere when we move it against the air. What's the equation of this surface (that is roughly a semisphere)? How can I find it? The minimal area principal doesn't seem to work anymore. Need I analyze the surface tension?

It should be something like this
[image]

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits to your question to make it appear at the top of the home page.

Comment: The surface is no longer minimal in terms of area; what is being minimized is presumably a combination of air pressure and area. The tricky part is that for stronger displacement the airflow and pressure depends on the shape. I suspect there is an analytic solution for the case where the displacement is small, but that it breaks down when the pressure becomes higher.